# Filter ng-repeat according to the first letter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

In AngularJS, I have an array of Objects. I want to display data filtered for the first letter. 
I used the following way.
**HTML**:

```
<p ng-repeat="film in filmList | startsWith:'C':'title'">{{film.title}}</p>
```

**JS**:

```
.filter('startsWith', () => {
    return (items: any, prefix: any, itemProperty: any) => {
        if (items && items.length) {
            return items.filter((item: any) => {
                var findIn = itemProperty ? item[itemProperty] : item;
                return findIn.toString().indexOf(prefix) === 0;
            });
        }
    };
});`
```

And it works. But now my target is to filter (always for the first letter) based on two choices. For example, filter movies whose title begins for 'B' or 'C'.

I've written the following code, but it doesnt work:

**HTML**:

```
 <p ng-repeat="film in filmList | startsWith:'[B, C]':'title'">{{film.title}}</p>
```

**JS**:

```
.filter('startsWith', () => {
    return (items: any, prefixes: any, itemProperty: any) => {
        if (items && items.length) {
        return items.filter((item: any) => {
            var findIn = itemProperty ? item[itemProperty] : item;
            for(let i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++){
                return findIn.toString().indexOf(prefixes[i]) === 0;
            }
        });
    }
    };
 });
```

Comment: Does it not work for both prefixes or does it work for the first one only?

Comment: It doesn't work for both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parameter `'[B, C]'` will be recognized as string not array. You shall define array in controller and transform it.

**UPD:**

when you invoke `return` in `for-loop`,  the loop will break. I have make some change to avoid this.

refer below code snippet(updated).

```js
var app = angular.module("app", [])
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.filmList = [{
      title: 'Black'
    },
    {
      title: 'Brown'
    },
    {
      title: 'Clown'
    },
    {
      title: 'Red'
    },
    {
      title: 'Gray'
    }
  ];
  $scope.option = ['B', 'C'];
})
app.filter('startsWith', () => {
  return (items, prefixes, itemProperty) => {
    if (items && items.length) {
      return items.filter((item) => {
        var findIn = itemProperty ? item[itemProperty] : item;
        
        for (let i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
          if (findIn.toString().indexOf(prefixes[i]) === 0) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-repeat="film in filmList | startsWith:option:'title'">{{film.title}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added a movie with a title that starts with 'C', but it doesn't work! I made a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/yIifro2YNhRgMuBaM13Y?p=preview

Comment: @panagulis72 there is something strange with `i` of `for-loop`, it is always `0` and never increment.

Comment: @Pengyy alternatively, you can just `return true` inside `if` and `return false` after loop.. currently it iterates even after finding one `true` :)

Comment: Thanks!! I've also founded another solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/B0JZdKVxgOfopUHVgDqa?p=preview

Comment: @panagulis72 plunker checked, they are similar. you can still use `Array.filter`, this will make your code brief.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something simpler without the need for an additional filter directive:

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.filmList = [{
    title: "Batman"
  }, {
    title: "CastAway"
  }, {
    title: "GodFather"
  }];

  $scope.customfilter = function(film) {
    return film.title.charAt(0) === 'B' || film.title.charAt(0) === 'C';
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p ng-repeat="film in filmList | filter: customfilter">{{film.title}}</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate soltion to keeping the `option` in controller is to produce an array from the string. For example, if `ng-repeat` has this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | startsWith:'B, C':'name'">
```

In filter, we could have `prefixes = prefixes.split(",")` to create the array. It would be something like,

```
app.filter('startsWith', function() {
  return function(items, prefixes, itemProperty) {
    if (items && items.length) {
      prefixes = prefixes.split(",")
      return items.filter(function(item) {
        var findIn = itemProperty ? item[itemProperty] : item;
        for(var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++){
          if(findIn.toString().indexOf(prefixes[i].trim()) === 0) {
            return true
          }
        }
        return false
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Notice the `.trim()` to remove extra spaces (if any)

Here's [**working example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/y6PVqwG9pA0KEnvMXDlb?p=preview)